# Multiple Replace in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, replaceall

How do I replace multiple words in a worksheet?

Words like: Da...da, Do...do, Dos, De... de.. etc.

How to adapt it in my spreadsheet called "Customers3"?

```vb
Public Function MyProper(MyString As String, Optional exceptions As Variant)

Dim c As Variant
If IsMissing(exceptions) Then
    exceptions = Array("a", "as", "e", "o", "os", "da", "das", "de", "di", "do", "dos",  _
      "CPF", "RG", "E-Mail")
End If

MyString = Application.Proper(MyString)

For Each c In exceptions
    MyString = Replace(" " & MyString & " ", " " & c & " ", " " & LCase(c) & " ", , , vbTextCompare)
Next c

MyProper = MyString

End Sub
```

Comment: How are you attempting to use this function?

Comment: I have several spreadsheets with customer data, names, addresses, and I used "ProperFunction" to get it right, but the particles were also capitalized with the first letter, and it shouldn't be. -Sorry, i don't know english very well

Comment: What happens when you use it in Excel? For example, `=MyProper(A1)`?

Comment: I need it to change in every spreadsheet and, as I'm still learning, I don't know how to insert it in the code.
Could you please show me how?

Answer (score 2):

One issue here:

```
MyString = Replace(" " & MyString & " ", " " & c & " ", " " & LCase(c) & " ", , , vbTextCompare)
```

every time you pass through the loop you add more spaces...

Also you have `End Sub` not `End Function`

Try this:

```vb
Public Function MyProper(MyString As String, Optional exceptions As Variant)

    Dim c As Variant
    If IsMissing(exceptions) Then
        exceptions = Array("a", "as", "e", "o", "os", "da", _
                           "das", "de", "di", "do", "dos", _
                           "CPF", "RG", "E-Mail")
    End If
    
    MyString = " " & Application.Proper(MyString) & " " 'in case exception at start/end
    
    For Each c In exceptions
        MyString = Replace(MyString, " " & c & " ", " " & LCase(c) & " ", , , vbTextCompare)
    Next c
    
    MyProper = Trim(MyString) 'remove any added spaces

End Function
```

Comment: Okay, when I get home, I'll try. But in advance, thank you very much.

Comment: Hi
I copied exactly as you posted, but nothing happened. I was using the bottom one, but it is very "heavy", it takes a long time to execute (there are many "Replaces"): .....>

Comment: Sub ProperCase()

  
    Dim rnge As range
   For Each rnge In Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues).Cells
        rnge.Value = StrConv(rnge.Value, vbProperCase)
       rnge.Value = Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(rnge.Value, _
        " Da ", " da "), " Das ", " das "), " De ", " de "), " Dos ", " dos "), " Do ", " do "), " A ", " a "), " O ", " o "), _
        " Os ", " os "), "Cpf", "CPF"), "Rg", "RG"), "E_mail", "E_Mail"), " E ", " e ")
    Next rnge
End Sub

Comment: This works for me as a function - it doesn't "do" anything by itself.

Answer (score 1):

### `Proper` Portuguese

```vb
Option Explicit

Function MyProper(ByVal MyString As String) As String

    Const ExceptionsList As String _
        = "a,as,e,o,os,da,das,de,di,do,dos,CPF,RG,E-Mail"
    Dim Exceptions() As String: Exceptions = Split(ExceptionsList, ",")
    
    Dim SubStrings() As String
    SubStrings = Split(Application.Proper(MyString), " ")
    
    Dim cIndex As Variant
    Dim n As Long
    For n = 0 To UBound(SubStrings)
        cIndex = Application.Match(SubStrings(n), Exceptions, 0)
        If IsNumeric(cIndex) Then
            SubStrings(n) = Exceptions(cIndex - 1)
        End If
    Next n
    
    MyProper = Join(SubStrings, " ")

End Function


Sub MyProperAllWorksheets()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rg As Range
    Dim Data As Variant
    Dim rCount As Long, cCount As Long
    Dim r As Long, c As Long
    
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        Set rg = ws.UsedRange
        rCount = rg.Rows.Count
        cCount = rg.Columns.Count
        If rCount > 1 Or cCount > 1 Then
            Data = rg.Value
        Else
            ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1): Data(1, 1) = rg.Value
        End If
        For r = 1 To rCount
            For c = 1 To cCount
                On Error Resume Next
                Data(r, c) = MyProper(Data(r, c))
                On Error GoTo 0
            Next c
        Next r
        rg.Value = Data
    Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi. I copied and pasted exactly as you sent, but nothing happened. The program didn't even think.

Comment: The procedure `MyProperAllWorksheets` is written for `ThisWorkbook`, i.e. the workbook containing this code. If you want to use it for another workbook, you should replace `ThisWorkbook` with `ActiveWorkbook`, or even better, with the workbook name, e.g. `Workbooks("Test.xlsx")`.

Comment: Muito obrigado! (Thank you very much). Always wear the mask. God be with you.

Comment: Perfeito, Amigo! Deu certo! Muito muito muito obrigado. Deus cuidará de vc sempre! (Perfect, Friend! It worked out! Thank you very very much. God will take care of you always!).